# python bokeh 2.0.0 does not render

Tags: python, bokeh, tornado, gunicorn

I recently updated bokeh from 1.4 to 2.0.0. I have a flask application with several bokeh servers. After updating, the bokeh servers no longer render properly(no plot, blank), there are no errors in the browser console or redhat shell. If I revert back to bokeh 1.4 + tornado 4.5.3, it renders normally. Can someone help me figure out what's happening?

Python 3.6.3
bokeh 2.0.0
tornado 6.0.4
redhat 4.8.5

edit: doing `bokeh serve myapp.py` individually for each bokeh server surprisingly works, it must be the way i'm deploying them through flask..the code below works on bokeh1.4 + tornado 4.5.3

```
# cycle through bokeh files and start bokeh servers
files = []
boks = []
for file in os.listdir("/mypath_to_bokeh/bokehs/"):
    if file.endswith('.py'):
        boks.append(file)
        file = "bokehs/" + file
        files.append(file)
boks = [os.path.splitext(x)[0] for x in boks]

argvs = {}
urls = []
for i in files:
    argvs[i] = None
    urls.append(i.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0])
host = 'myhost'

apps = build_single_handler_applications(files, argvs)

bokeh_tornado = BokehTornado(apps, extra_websocket_origins=["hoststring"]) 
bokeh_http = HTTPServer(bokeh_tornado)                    
sockets, port = bind_sockets("ipstring", 0) 
bokeh_http.add_sockets(sockets)

def serve(name):
    @app.route("/{}".format(name), endpoint=str(name))
    #@login_required
    #@bokeh_access
    def func():
        bokeh_script = server_document("ipstring:%d/%s" % (port, name)) 
        gc.collect()
        return render_template("bokserv.html", bokeh_script=bokeh_script)

    func.__name__ = name
    gc.collect()
    return func

all_serve_functions = [serve(name) for name in boks]
```

Comment: Unfortunately without a *complete, minimal reproducer* that can actually be run and investigated, it's not really possible to speculate. All I can do is point you at this working example (just verified) from the repo as a reference: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/flask_embed.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something I accidentally omitted from the posted code was that I had at the end of my application:

```
def bk_worker():
    asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
    bokeh_tornado = BokehTornado(apps, extra_websocket_origins=["localhost:8000"]) 
    bokeh_http = HTTPServer(bokeh_tornado)                     
    sockets, port = bind_sockets("localhost", 0) #PROBLEM LINE
    bokeh_http.add_sockets(sockets)
    server = BaseServer(IOLoop.current(), bokeh_tornado, bokeh_http)
    server.start()
    server.io_loop.start()

t = Thread(target=bk_worker)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```

Extracting out the `#PROBLEM LINE` and putting it before the `bk_worker()` function returned functionality of bokeh for the most part, now it's time to refactor all the deprecated code.